# Power stage of a buck converter as VCCS

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

In a buck converter using current-mode control as control loop, why can the power stage be seen as a voltage-controlled current source? Is it possible to understand that from a simple equation?

Comment: The inner current loop (usually) takes a voltage input from the voltage loop, and controls the current in the inductor.  So within the bandwidth of the current loop, you have a voltage-controlled current source.

Comment: Because you're controlling an output current with an input voltage? I'm not sure what you're asking about that isn't by definition...

Comment: In addition to others' comments, note that the VCCS behaviour is true for frequencies lower than crossover frequency. So the L effectively disappears for DC (or very low frequencies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A current-mode buck converter can indeed be modeled with a current source driven by the error voltage setpoint. This is the foundation of the [PWM switch model](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Papers/Analysis%20of%20CM%20Controlled%20PWM%20Converters.pdf) in current mode introduced by Vatché Vorpérian in 1990. See below a picture excerpted from my [APEC 2013](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf) seminar:

[image]

In this CCM model, the inductor current is externally set by the current source and \$L\$ disappears from the control-to-output transfer function. You no longer have the peak incurred to the resonating \$LC\$ as in voltage-mode control.

Another way of looking at this is to consider the duty ratio \$D\$: in both cases, voltage- or current-mode control (fixed frequency of course), the control variable remains the duty ratio. In VM, the error voltage *directly* controls the duty ratio while, in current mode, the error voltage sets the inductor peak current and thus *indirectly* controls the duty ratio. In the end, operating points between a VM and a CM converter operated in similar conditions are rigorously similar in steady state. The difference between the two lies in the way the duty ratio is elaborated and it affects the dynamics of the converters.

Capitalizing on this observation, I built a [small presentation](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Duty%20ratio%20factory%20modeling.pdf) showing how associating a voltage-mode power stage with a separate modulator lead to the same control-to-output transfer function than that obtained with the CM PWM switch model:

[image]

However, this simple approach does not predict subharmonic instabilities and a more complex model needs to be considered. This is what Ray Ridley did in his thesis from 1990 where he used a different modulator built after sampled-data analysis. I looked at it in a recent [paper](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/2101/articles/H2PToday2101_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) published in [How2Power](https://www.how2power.com/newsletters/).